# Using Ember.set to change a value, getting error that I have to use Ember.set

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In my application, I have to update a record (eventToUpdate) with the data from another object (updatedEvent). To do this, I use the following code:

```
editEvent (updatedEvent, eventToUpdate) {
  eventToUpdate.set('name', updatedEvent.name);
  eventToUpdate.set('matching', updatedEvent.matching);
  eventToUpdate.set('dcfEvent', updatedEvent.dcfEvent);

  eventToUpdate.save().then(() => {
    toastr.success('Event updated');
  }).catch((error) => {
    toastr.error('There occured an error while trying to update the event');
    console.log(error);
  });
},
```

When I try to update the event, I get the following error:

```
Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `name` property (of [object Object]) to `DCF tests`."
```

I have also tried setting the values with Ember.set, like this:

```
Ember.set(eventToUpdate, 'name', updatedEvent.name);
```

But that gives the same result..

I use Ember.js 1.13

Comment: Are you sure eventToUpdate is record ?. you please provide console.log(eventToUpdate) ...Ember.set should definitely solve Assertion error.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that `eventToUpdate` is not an [Ember Object](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html) and someone is watching this property. So use `Ember.set` to set values:

```
editEvent (updatedEvent, eventToUpdate) {
  Ember.set(eventToUpdate, 'name', updatedEvent.name);
  Ember.set(eventToUpdate, 'matching', updatedEvent.matching);
  Ember.set(eventToUpdate, 'dcfEvent', updatedEvent.dcfEvent);

  eventToUpdate.save().then(() => {
    toastr.success('Event updated');
  }).catch((error) => {
    toastr.error('There occured an error while trying to update the event');
    console.log(error);
  });
},
```

Comment: I have also tried that solution, but same result.. I'll add it to the post though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in the structure of my data. I was trying to edit sub events, which are part of a root event. The problem was solved by first loading the single subevent from the backend and then editing that single subevent. It looks somewhat like this:

```
var event = this.store.findRecord('event', subevent.id);
event.set('name', updatedEvent.name);
event.set('matching', updatedEvent.matching);

event.save().then(() => {
  toastr.success('element successfully updated');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: findRecord returns Promise.